# How to add multiple javascript by wp_register_script?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

i have multiple javascript file. How can i add those to wordpress by wp_register_script ? I can add single javascript file by

```
function wptuts_scripts_with_jquery() {
    wp_register_script( 'custom-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/custom-script.js', array( 'jquery' ) );

    // For either a plugin or a theme, you can then enqueue the script:
    wp_enqueue_script( 'custom-script' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wptuts_scripts_with_jquery' );
```

Comment: Repeat the same for more scripts, you can't add multiple in one call AFAIK.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but i am not clear your answer. Can you give me a example ?

Comment: You have to repeat `wp_register_script` and `wp_enqueue_script` for each script you want to add.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a `common function` for this and call it for every `script` like,

```
function wptuts_scripts_with_jquery()
{
    // create array of all scripts
    $scripts=array('custom-script'=>'/js/custom-script.js',
                  'custom-script1'=>'/js/custom-script1.js',
                  'custom-script2'=>'/js/custom-script2.js');
    foreach($scripts as $key=>$sc)
    {
       wp_register_script( $key, get_template_directory_uri() . $sc, array('jquery') );
       wp_enqueue_script( $key );
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wptuts_scripts_with_jquery' );
```